# An $M$-sequence stays an $M$-sequence after localization.

Tags: ring-theory, commutative-algebra

> Let $R$ be a Noetherian ring, $M$ a finite $R$-module, and $\bf{x}$ an $M$-sequence.
>
> (a) Suppose that a prime ideal $\mathfrak{p} \in Supp(M)$ contains $\bf{x}$. Then $\bf{x}$ (as a sequence in $R_\mathfrak{p}$) is an $M_\mathfrak{p}$-sequence. (Bruns and Herzog Corollary 1.1.3)

This is proven by noting that localization is flat and by using Nakayama's Lemma. But I'm not really sure why we need $R$ to be Noetherian. Is it really necessary?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Localization is always flat, over any ring, and Nakayama lemma deals with finite modules over any ring, so the proof that Bruns and Herzog give makes no use of noetherianity.

The hypothesis on $R$ being noetherian is stated for part (b) of the same Corollary 1.1.3: they use the fact that $\hat{M} \cong M\otimes_R \hat{R}$.